# Pandas Rolling: Return Min and Max Dates, Sum of Exposure

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to implement a rolling window and am struggling with the very last part.  As you can see below, the code returns the sum of exposure, attached to the last date in the rolling window.  I also want a column that has the first date in the window as well.  (they are ordered by date but I am ultimately after the min and max dates for each window as well as the sum of exposure).  Trying to take the date out of the index and using min and max function on it produces this error:
NotImplementedError: ops for Rolling for this dtype datetime64[ns] are not implemented

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=24, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID1': ['A']*24,
        'ID2': ['B']*24,
        'Date': dates,
        'EXPOSURE':[1]*24
    }
)

df.set_index(['ID1','ID2','Date'], inplace=True)

result = df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).rolling(12, min_periods = 12).sum()
result.head(100)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPI1L.png)

Comment: could you show an example of your dataframe output?

Comment: Added the output i am getting now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Operations on rolling windows are actually limited to aggregation functions
and must be performed on **numbers**, not on **dates**.

To circumvent this limitation, notice that the Date from the beginning of
your rolling window of size 12 is actually the Date from 11-th row before.

So you can:

- generate *result* just as you do,
- call `result2 = df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).Date.shift(11)`,
- drop 2 top levels from MultiIndex of *result* and merge both results.